# Unification algorithm infers too concrete types

Tags: idris

I was trying to create Tuples of size n in Idris:

```
module NTuple

data Tuple : Vect n Type -> Type where
  EmptyTuple : Tuple Nil
  TupleItem : a -> Tuple types -> Tuple (a :: types)


mapN : {types : Vect n Type} -> (i : Fin (S n)) -> (a -> b) -> Tuple (insertAt i a types) -> Tuple (insertAt i b types)
mapN fZ     f (TupleItem x xs) = TupleItem (f x) xs
mapN (fS i) f (TupleItem x xs) = TupleItem x (mapN i f xs)
```

But I'm getting this error in the last line:

> ```
> When elaborating left hand side of mapN: 
> When elaborating an application of NTuple.mapN:
>     Can't unify
>             Tuple (a :: types)
>     with
>             Tuple (insertAt (fS i) a types)
>
>     Specifically:
>             Can't unify
>                     a :: types
>             with
>                     insertAt (fS i) a types
> ```

Is there a way to make this function work?

Comment: what `mapN` is supposed to do?

Comment: to map over the i type in the tuple

Comment: You need to eliminate one absurd pattern as in the `insertAt` function. Here is how it looks in Agda: http://lpaste.net/108544

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `insertAt (FS i) a types` can't be reduced without knowing anything about `types`. If we knew `types = t :: ts` then it could be reduced to `t :: insertAt i ts`.

But in the second case of `mapN`, we *do* know that `types` is exactly of that form:

1. Our first argument is `FS i`
2. Implying `n = S m` for some `m`...
3. Meaning our implicit `types` argument has type `Vect (S m) Type`
4. Which means it is of the form `t :: ts`!

Once we point this out to Idris, it is happy to reduce `insertAt (FS i) a types` and thus, your code typechecks:

```
mapN : {types : Vect n Type} -> (i : Fin (S n)) -> (a -> b) -> Tuple (insertAt i a types) -> Tuple (insertAt i b types)
mapN                  FZ     f (TupleItem x xs) = TupleItem (f x) xs
mapN {types = _ :: _} (FS i) f (TupleItem x xs) = TupleItem x (mapN i f xs)
mapN {types = []}     (FS i) _ _                = absurd i
```

Comment: Why do we need to point this out to Idris? Why can't Idris figure this out on it's own?